# What is this electronic symbol?

Tags: motor, schematics, wiring, symbol

I am trying to repurpose a scavenged motor, however the wiring diagram that's on it has a schematic symbol I have never seen and could not find on the Internet.

Anyone know what this is and what it means?

[image: Mystery symbol]

For more context, here's a reproduction of the entire schematic:

[image: Whole schematic]

**Update:**

The symbol is for a thermal switch/contact. This particular kind is normally closed and opens on temperature rise (http://www.industrial-electronics.com/Electricity-Refrigeration-Heating-Air-Conditioning_5b.html)

Comment: It reminds me of a temperature switch. It looks like the device is built into your motor, can you possibly identify it physically?

Comment: From the context I would guess that it indicates a switch controlled by a digital input on the yellow wire.

Comment: "PWM controlled switch", perhaps? (also, just guessing)

Comment: It's likely a Negative Temperature Coefficient (NTC) switch, designed to allow starting torque to be generated in a single-phase motor.  Initially it's very low resistance, allowing current to flow through a capacitor (the starting cap), causing a phase shift of the AC... causing torque in the 'stalled' motor, starting the spin.  As the 'switch' heats up due to current flow, it's resistance rises, eventually removing the starting cap's phase shift, since it's not needed after the motor is rotating.  Look up single-phase AC motors and starting capacitors.

Comment: @DerStrom8 -- I could be wrong, but all of the images I've found of this symbol with the squiggle away from the switch refer to this as being open normally.

Comment: @conan I first want to clarify that my "edit" was actually an edit of an edit. The initial change was not mine. That being said, what would be the point of a thermal switch that only closes when the motor gets too hot? How is a motor going to get hot if it's disconnected? Logically it would only make sense for the switch to open (turn off the motor) when it gets too hot (meaning it's drawing excessive current and is overheating).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a thermal contact (Normally closed - thermal trip).

If OP Googles "contact switch symbols" and jumps to the Images, he/she can find a lot of symbol tables. Here's one OP could see: [ibiblio.org/kuphaldt/electricCircuits/Ref/01053.png](http://ibiblio.org/kuphaldt/electricCircuits/Ref/01053.png)

Comment: Yes! Looks like it's a thermal switch.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, another term for this kind of device *thermal cutoff* ([here](http://www.mouser.com/Thermal-Management/Thermal-Cutoffs/_/N-5gfz/) and [here](http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en/circuit-protection/thermal-cutoffs-cutouts-tco/655696)).  Some of these devices are self-resetting, some of them need manual reset, some of them are sacrificial (like glass fuses).